# Slowed app in C# form

Tags: c#, performance, tor-browser-bundle

I start app and set is as child in form app. But app is slow and when I open new tab when loading another page app falldown.

```
Process p = Process.Start("C:/Users/---/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
appWin = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);
```

I use thread because I need to wait to connect browser and open it, than set it.
Is there any option how to make it faster give to process more resources?

Comment: Is there a reason you are telling your current thread to sleep? Maybe include more information and some more sample code related to what you are trying to do.. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the intention behind sleeping the UI thread by 7 seconds as can be seen in your code. You shouldn't do that and moreover, consider running that external `exe` in a separate thread than UI thread.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
```

Comment: I do it just one time only there because I need to wait to connect to tor network and open browser than set it as child